# MongoDB C# 2.0 - LINQ query alternative to AsQueryable

Tags: linq, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Here's what my model looks like

```
public class Bios
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("init")]
    public string Init { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With MongoDB C# driver 1.10, I'm able to do the following and get the right results.  I get a string list of initials.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> InitList(MongoCollection mongoCollection)
{
    return mongoCollection.AsQueryable<Bios>().Select(b => b.ResAnInit);
}
```

However, I upgraded the driver to 2.0.1 and tried to get the same results.  With the help of Resharper, I modified the method to this:

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> InitList(IMongoCollection<Bios> mongoCollection)
{
    return await mongoCollection.Find(x => x.Init != null)
        .Project(Builders<Bios>.Projection.Include(y => y.Init).Exclude("_id"))
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

I get errors now.  How can I fix this to do what I did with C# driver 1.10?

Comment: LINQ isn't yet available for 2.x. It will be coming in 2.1. For now, have you tried Project(b => b.ResAnInit)? It takes an expression as well.

Comment: I just changed my code.  Now, I'm getting the following error:  System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>> does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.  What should I do now?

Comment: Downgrade to the 1.10 driver

Comment: The problem is simply that you are attempting to enumerate a Task<IEnumerable<T>>. You need to await it (or call .Result or .GetAwaiter().GetResult()) before iterating.